# facebook mobile access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, mobile

In one of our FB app on mobile, we want to store the FB Access Token on to backend to be able to:

1. extend the access token to long lived
2. use them to do certain tasks on behalf of user from our backend server

Is it possible to do these using app tokens obtained using fb js sdk?

Thanks,
Janar